# Radiobuttons in different group boxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, radio-button

Quite a silly question, but still annoying.

The thing is that i have two group boxes where the titles have radiobuttons covering the group box titles.

Something like

```
(x) I want pizza
*Pizza stuff*

( ) I want Hamburger
*Hamburger stuff*
```

Since they're now in different group boxes, they can both be selected.
Is there a way to set/force the radiobuttons to be in the same "group"? Like in HTML where you set 
`name="WhatToEat" value="Pizza"` for the first value and then 
`name="WhatToEat" value="Hamburger"`

Or can i set the title for the groupbox to behave like a radio button or something?

Of course i can have the radio button outside the grop boxes, but i think having the titles as radiobuttons just makes the most sense and looks nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have all your RadioButtons on a form. You can use a RadioButton variable to mark what is currently checked. Every time user checks a RadioButton, if it's not the currently checked RadioButton, make the currently checked RadioButton unchecked, and set the currently checked RadioButton to that RadioButton.

Here is my code:

```
public Form1(){
  InitializeComponents();
  currentChecked = radioButton1;
}
//Suppose the initially checked radio is radioButton1
RadioButton currentChecked;
//This is the CheckedChanged event handler used for all the radiobuttons
private void radioButtonChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        RadioButton r = (RadioButton)sender;
        if (r != currentChecked)
        {
            currentChecked.Checked = false;
            currentChecked = r;
        }
}
```

My code is much simpler without using any loop. It costs the additional `currentChecked` but it's not much.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a really nice solution!

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've done whenever I encountered the problem like yours. :)

Comment: I don't get it:  "If you have all your RadioButtons on a form."  If all the RadioButtons are on the Form, then they are all in the same Group, and they already exhibit this behavior.  Why do you need the code then to uncheck the last RadioButton?...they already do that by themselves!

Comment: @Idle_Mind I mean you can access every RadioButton in the Form class, but they are not added to Controls of the Form. RadioButtons on the same form doesn't mean they have to be added to Controls of the form. Thanks, by the way, my English is not good enough to express exactly what I want to mean.

Answer (score 1):

No, it have to in one group ..

But for that case you can control in checked_change event

```
Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    RadioButton1.Checked = Not RadioButton2.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    RadioButton2.Checked = Not RadioButton1.Checked
End Sub
```

Comment: This is used only for 2 radiobuttons, the general answer should solve the general case in which there are many radiobuttons.

Comment: Yea, this is actually what I came up with after asking this question. It does not feel right, but I guess i have to go with this soultion in this case. thx :)

Comment: @KingKing Yep, that's what i mean. It should be some workaraound for this. If the radiobuttons were generated by some kind of loop it would be another annoying loop for checking what radiobutton that is checked.

Comment: @gubbfett : You need it for more than 2 rb ?

Comment: Actually not for the moment, but it's still interesting to find out if someone has done this before and has another soulution and actually puts them in the same group even if they're in different boxes. As a web dev I think this could be done in a more "correct" way.

Comment: @gubbfett : So, upvote or maybe vote as answer will fair enough .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just move them to the Form at run-time.  Use PointToScreen() and PointToClient() to keep them in the same position as you placed them at desing-time.  So you'd replace "RadioButton1", "RadioButton2", and "RadioButton3" with your title RadioButtons:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim RadioTitles() As RadioButton = {RadioButton1, RadioButton2, RadioButton3}
    For Each rb As RadioButton In RadioTitles
        Dim pt As Point = Me.PointToClient(rb.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)))
        Me.Controls.Add(rb)
        rb.Location = pt
        rb.BringToFront()
    Next
End Sub
```

*You could put a value into the Tag() property of each RadioButton that should be the "title" and then search for those instead of hard-coding them into the array.  Or maybe you could name them a certain way.

EDIT: You could make the "title" RadioButtons enable/disable their associated GroupBoxes when they are checked like this:
[image: RadioButton GroupBox Title]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim RadioTitles() As RadioButton = {RadioButton1, RadioButton2, RadioButton3}
    For Each rb As RadioButton In RadioTitles
        rb.Parent.Enabled = False
        rb.Tag = rb.Parent
        AddHandler rb.CheckedChanged, AddressOf TitleRadioButtons_CheckedChanged

        Dim pt As Point = Me.PointToClient(rb.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)))
        Me.Controls.Add(rb)
        rb.Location = pt
        rb.BringToFront()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TitleRadioButtons_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
    If Not IsNothing(rb.Tag) AndAlso TypeOf rb.Tag Is Control Then
        Dim ctl As Control = DirectCast(rb.Tag, Control)
        ctl.Enabled = rb.Checked
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not how radio buttons work.

As I'm sure you're aware, radio buttons get their grouping from containers.  *To my knowledge*, if you want to be able to accomplish what you're asking, you'll probably need to code a custom solution.  For instance, you could place an **event handler** on each radio button to fire off the same event to uncheck other boxes, e.g.

```
radioButton1.CheckedChanged += anyRadioButton_CheckedChanged;
radioButton2.CheckedChanged += anyRadioButton_CheckedChanged;
radioButton3.CheckedChanged += anyRadioButton_CheckedChanged;

...

private void anyRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var control in this.Controls)
    {
        if(control is GroupBox)
        {
            foreach (var childControl in ((GroupBox)control).Controls)
            {
                if (childControl is RadioButton && childControl != sender)
                {
                    ((RadioButton)childControl).Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is recommended for the use of loop when we can avoid it.

Comment: @KingKing Care to expand on why?

Comment: Please see my answer to understand why I say using Loop in this case is not recommended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set text of the `GroupBox` to empty string and put `RadioButton` over it. The trick is to put it on form actually but move it the way it looks like part of `GroupBox`. But this is sufficient only if your group boxes are static and won't be moved. Otherwise it is better to use solution which @matzone proposed. But even in that case you can put all radio buttons in collection in your code and use the only event handler for all of them. Something like

```
private List<RadioButton> radioButtons;

public YourFormConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    radioButtons.Add(radio1);
    radioButtons.Add(radio2);
    radioButtons.Add(radio3);
    foreach (var radio in radioButtons)
        radio.CheckedChanged += RadioCheckedChanged;
}

private void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var thisRadio = sender as RadioButton;
    if (!thisRadio.Checked)
        return;
    foreach (var radio in radioButtons)
        if (radio != thisRadio)
            radio.Checked = false;
}
```